# Angularjs plugin installation error

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, plugins

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Tern Toolings 1.1.0.201511082254 (tern.eclipse.ide.tools.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.201511082254)
  Missing requirement: Tern - Eclipse 1.1.0.201511082254 (tern.eclipse 1.1.0.201511082254) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.swt 3.7.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Tern - Eclipse - Core IDE 1.1.0.201511082254 (tern.eclipse.ide.core 1.1.0.201511082254)
    To: bundle tern.eclipse 0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the "requires 'bundle org.eclipse.swt 3.7.0'" message - version 3.7.0 or newer of SWT is required.

It looks like your version of Eclipse is out of date, you need Eclipse 3.7 or 3.8 or Eclipse 4.2 or later.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i dont know what the issue was,.. it worked now:D